# В файле txt записана строка 1 2 3 4, когда пытаюсь вызвать и записать в массив и принтую мне выводит [<map object at 0x10115a1d0>]

Tags: python

[image: В файле txt записана строка 1234, когда пытаюсь вызвать и записать в массив 1,2,3,4 и принтую мне выводит [<map object at 0x10115a1d0>]]

Реализуйте на Python простейшую программу, которая будет считывать из файла числа, а далее отдельными функциями искать среди этих чисел считать их общую сумму и произведение.

Числа в файле записаны в одной строке, друг от друга отделены пробелами. В файле есть минимум одно число.

Comment: Приложите код и полученный stacktrace в текстовом виде, а не в виде скриншота

Answer (score 0):

вот так сделайте

```
a = [*map(...)]
```

или так:

```
a = [[float(v) for v in line.split("\t")] for line in file]
```

или так:

```
a = [list(map(float, line.split("\t"))) for line in file]
```